# 'Go back' browser button returns white page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added a piece of code, to make the anchor links' jump to another page smoother.

```
    $('.link-fade').click(function(){
      var href= $(this).attr('href');

      // do animation
      $('body').fadeOut( 500, function(){
            // go to link when animation completes
            window.location=href;
      })

      // over ride browser following link when clicked
      return false;
})
```

**The problem:** When I press a link, and after that hit the 'back' browser button, sometimes it makes the whole page white and load nothing.

P.S: I have pace.js included too in my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning false, try this

```
$('.link-fade').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  var href= $(this).attr('href');

  // do animation
  $('body').fadeOut( 500, function(){
        // go to link when animation completes
        window.location=href;
  });
});
```

Comment: Kinda fixed the issue, Firefox still returns white page tho. Everything else seems fine. Care to explain a bit why it worked? :P

Comment: @Andrew Browser has some default actions linked to elements on a page. So to prevent those actions the correct way is using preventDefault() function. Returning false may stop the browser from doing some post processing like storing the proper return url(in this case the current page url)

Comment: Thanks, but since firefox doesn't work with PreventDefault, it will never work i guess right?